# How to set value for provider gathered from API backend in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-module, angular-providers

how can I set value here from API ?

[image]

Comment: Why not just inject a service that retrieves the value from the API, and store that value in the service?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I'm trying but I can't solve it .. I'm using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-tag-manager and I've got problems with setting this googleTagManagerId field

Comment: Ah, I see. It's for a third party library. You probably want to inject via an async function, which doesn't currently exist. Seems like it's been an open issue for a while https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory

In a module initialize the service and call the API

```
export function setupFactory(myService:MyService) {
  return () => myService.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,  useFactory: setupFactory, deps: [MyService], multi: true }, ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you can call a function to get the API key

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'}) 
export class MyService {

  private _apiKey = '';

  public apiKey(): string {
    return this._apiKey;
  }

  public async load() {
    // Simulate calling the API
    this._apiKey = await new Promise((r) => {
      r('you api key')
    })
  }
}

let apiFactory = (MyService: MyService) => {
  return MyService.apiKey();
}


providers: [{ provide: 'googleTagManagerId',  useFactory: apiFactory, deps: [MyService] }]
```

Comment: How would you do that ? I have to set this googleTagManagerId with a Value

Comment: Ive had a look and useFactory is best. Please see my example above.

Comment: But the key comes from an API, so requires an async call.

Answer (score 0):

You would ideally achieve this via an async factory in your providers. Unfortunately that has been an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279) for a while.

A workaround could be to create a wrapper service that loads the api key first time through and then replays the loaded service from a subject.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'}) 
export class ServiceWrapper {

  private service$: Subject<Service>;

  getService(): Observable<Service> {
    if (this.service$) {
      return this.service$.pipe(
        take(1)
      );
    }

    this.service$ = new ReplaySubject<Service>(1);

    this.http.get(apiKeyUrl).subscribe(apiKey => {
      this.service$.next(new Service(apiKey));
    });

    return this.service$.pipe(
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

You would then inject this wrapper service into the components (or whatever consumes it):

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private service: ServiceWrapper) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getService().pipe(
      switchMap(service => service.method())
    ).subscribe(result => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

You will end up with a lot of `switchMap` calls, so isn't ideal, but is one workaround.

If you had any other dependencies you needed to inject into the service, you would also inject those into your wrapper service.

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wlbyqp